# JS handle catching all the errors in all pages with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular js and i am trying to catch all the errors in all pages, but the problem that it does not catch the errors in all pages, for example i am doing ReferenceError in one of the controllers and it does not catch this.

```
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function() {

    window.onerror = function( msg, url, line, col, error ) {

      var extra = !col ? '' : '\ncolumn: ' + col;
      extra += !error ? '' : '\nerror: ' + error;

      var data = {
        msg : msg,
        url : url,
        line: line + extra
      }
      alert('error');

      var suppressErrorAlert = true;

      return suppressErrorAlert;
    };
}
```

How can i make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use window.onerror, instead use $exceptionHandler.
 Angular has a global $exceptionHandler factory that catches errors that happen inside controllers, services, etc.

> Any uncaught exception in angular expressions is delegated to this service.

```
angular.module('exceptionOverride', []).factory('$exceptionHandler', 

function() {
  return function(exception, cause) {
    exception.message += ' (caused by "' + cause + '")';
    throw exception;
  };
});
```

> This example will override the normal action of $exceptionHandler, to make angular exceptions fail hard when they happen, instead of just logging to the console.

More info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler

Nice blog post: http://blog.loadimpact.com/blog/exception-handling-in-an-angularjs-web-application-tutorial/